# Modem and Router on same subnet, but network doesn't work properly

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp

Now I'm looking for more information why do my network file sharing doesn't work properly even if I made router to be part of LAN. I'll explain all my possible changes I can remember. I chosen to merge both of devices into same subnet.

---

**Wiring**

Modem has DSL connected so internet is available.

PC1 <-LAN-> Modem <-LAN-> Router <-LAN-> PC2

---

**Modem**

LAN IP: 192.168.1.1

Subnet: 255.255.255.0

DHCP: ON (Range: 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.-199)

---

**Router**

LAN IP: 192.168.1.200

Subnet: 255.255.255.0

DHCP: ON (Range: 192.168.1.211 - 192.168.1.254)

*I want DHCP it to be enabled, because only 200-210 ending addresses will be static ones. Rest of users are friends or such.*

---

**PC1 (Connected to Modem)**

IP: 192.168.1.204

Subnet: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.1.1

---

**PC2 (Connected to Router)**

IP: 192.168.1.205

Subnet: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.1.1

---

**All what I have noticed**

- Router is pure-NAT router and NAT cannot be turned off for some reason. There's no such a option. (TP-Link WR940N)
- I see the both of devices on explorer's Network section (PC1, PC2), but they can only connect to themselves, but not each others.
- Both are on Private network profile and both has folder shared which has permissions to "Everyone - read & write"
- Both have access to internet too.
- Logging into Modem's Administrator Web-UI I can see both of devices as clients in client list: (PC1 - 192.168.1.205, PC2 - 192.168.1.206)
- Explorer says from PC1: "Windows cannot access... Problem can be in network", but I cannot find any problems in my configurations. Private network file and printer sharing is turned on.

Many people may think why do I have router between modem and PC2. Actual reason is that I like to play with devices and I want to learn much more about them.

Comment: Why is it a requirement to have DHCP be running on both devices? The TP-Link's DHCP server will by default tell clients to use the TP-Link as their gateway, which is certainly _not_ what you want in this setup.

Comment: (And while this suggestion is mostly off topic... for learning, get a Mikrotik router. They're amazingly flexible considering the price – no "NAT cannot be turned off" nonsense.)

Comment: I'm interested about router you mentioned, thank you. Actually now I turned the DHCP off on TP-Link. It makes PC2 able to connect to PC1, but not mutual.

Comment: Have you connected the router to the modem as [LAN-to-LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sbmx.png)?

Comment: Yes. It's connected like mentioned above. Seems that we got a little bit forward with Wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Router is pure-NAT router and NAT cannot be turned off for some reason. There's no such a option. (TP-Link WR940N)

Fortunately, that's not important *as long as* no devices actually use 192.168.1.200 as their gateway. That's the only way they'd reach the "router" part of the device – so as long as they don't, all data simply short-circuits through the built-in Ethernet switch chip, and the "router" CPU just sits there doing nothing.

The gateway is never used for same-subnet communications, anyway. As long as both computers know the correct netmask, they will send packets directly to each other.

So on the whole, your configuration looks like it should work perfectly fine. Since it doesn't, you have at least two things to check:

1. Make sure the firewall rules are right. Open `wf.msc`, the firewall rules editor. Under the "Incoming" section make sure the necessary "File Sharing" rules are enabled. (For access by `\\IP`, at minimum SMB-over-TCP via port 445 must be allowed.)
2. Make sure PC1 and PC2 have learned each other's correct MAC address via ARP. On Windows, you can run `arp -a` to see the ARP cache.
3. Make sure packets sent by PC1 are received by PC2, and vice versa. Install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on both systems, and start a capture on the Ethernet adapter.

   You can set a capture filter such as `arp or icmp or udp or (tcp port 445)` or a display filter such as `arp || icmp || udp || tcp.port == 445` to filter out irrelevant web traffic. *(Capture filters are set before starting the capture; display filters are set while capture is running. Their syntaxes are different.)*

   The capture is unaffected by firewall settings. If a packet is coming in, but the OS isn't reacting to it, that usually indicates a problem with the firewall's "incoming" rules.

Comment: Sorry I have to reform my comment... SRVSVC says NetShareEnumAll response, Error: WERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: There are _share-level_ permissions and there are _file-level_ permissions. Both must allow acccess. (And of course you must be allowed to 'log in' to the fileserver in the first place – for example the account's password must not be blank.)

Comment: Does NetShareEnumAll happen before authentication or afterwards? I somewhat suspect some of the "server's" security settings might be wonky, but I have no idea which.

Comment: Happens just before this. Shows "NetShareEnumAll request" which comes from LAN machine that is trying to connect. File and printer share is turned on in private network profile which is active. But I think I can mark your answer as solution, because it seems that the problem just hopped to permission errors.

Comment: @Epz Can you run `secpol.msc` and check whether ["Disallow anonymous enumeration of shares"](https://a.uguu.se/AgQVJsC47AgK.png) under "Security options" is disabled or not?

Comment: There's no secpol.msc for me I guess. At least what I read from internet it's not available for Windows Home users. I forgot mention that in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85384/discussion-between-epz-and-grawity).